# Creating a GUI Class in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface

What I'm thinking of doing is creating a class for my little subview, so I can use it over and over again. Specifically, in my project, I need a colored rectangular and a label, and between those subviews those are the ones gonna change. Thus, I want a class that represent that two components as one component.

I'm trying to use swing. Before, I used acm package which gave me convenient way of doing it, but I can't solve that problem with swing. So, the problem starts here, I couldn't figure out how to create a custom GUI class for a subview.

I want to put them in a for loop later, so I want to handle the case in once rather than writing for 20 times manually.

Any help would be appreciated,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your custom class so that it extends a `JPanel`. From there, you can add your common subcomponents, which sets each one up by passing parameters through the constructor, and then implement any common behaviours with methods on that class.

Comment: So, subclassing from JPanel is the solution, you are telling?

Comment: @KutayDemireren, precisely. If you predefine the subcomponents you want within this class that extends `JPanel` then you can instantiate as many as you need and attach them the same way you would attach a `JPanel` since it's just a subclass.

Comment: Yeah, I subclassed from JPanel and they attached together. That is I was searching for, thanks

Comment: No problem, @KutayDemireren.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Window Builder](https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAAahUKEwjn6Jas3rLIAhUi2qYKHSWRBck&url=https%3A%2F%2Feclipse.org%2Fwindowbuilder%2F&usg=AFQjCNHnlPK2qLrYL9MhXcs1s_RAnDcAQg&sig2=V8pgHkZRvM7ZcALc1EFGKw) plugin for eclipse for drag and drop editor. You could try to figure what's going wrong by organizing you objects.

Comment: Thanks, I prefer coding.

Comment: This is a general tool for GUI design, not a technical solution to the question.